# OSStatus -9809 while decryption

Tags: iphone, rsa

I am trying to implement an rsa encryption and decryption algorithm as a part of my app in iphone.(xcode 4.2,ios sdk 5.0)
I am generating keys using SecKeyGeneratePair and encrypting using SecKeyEncrypt.
Both these return  OSStatus 0.

But while decrypting using SecKeyDecrypt ,I get OSStatus as -9809.
Please help; where have i gone wrong.

Edit: Thanks for the quick response.
I copied and pasted the code from the following link:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17242-rsa-generating-keypair-so-slowly.html

Comment: Post some of your code. We don't have anything to go on here.

Comment: No one can answer with whatever info you have provided in your question...But have you using padding in encryption and decryption..Try with kSecPaddingNone

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured it out!! The error was because of the buffer size issue.

Answer (score 12):

The reason is that there is a typo on the [Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html)

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:dataLength];
```

It should be:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
```

Comment: 1000% CORRECT! Needs to be marked as correct answer!